# How to init Objects/Data in Android correctly

Tags: java, android

i am wondering how can i init Objects in my Activity correctly without getting NPE?
Normally I am initialising my Objects in the onCreate() method but when I do so I can't access them later in for example in an onClick() method.
What is the right way to do it?

Thanks Jérôme

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

Button sendButton;
EditText textMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    EditText textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
}

public void sendMessage() {
   setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
   String actualMessage = textMessage.getText().toString();
   System.out.println(actualMessage);
}
```

Comment: you declaring new variable in oncreate just remove that

Comment: Your `onClick` method (I'm guessing `sendMessage`) should accept a `View` argument.

Answer (score 1):

Simply remove the types `Button` and `EditText` when you initialize them in `onCreate`. Having the type when you set it equal to a view declares a new variable, instead of referencing the class variables.

```
sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

Now you can use this control anywhere in this activity

```
Button sendButton;
EditText textMessage;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
     sendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
     textMessage = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.message);
}
```